# Symfony run event after expiration command

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I develop in symfony 6 as part of my application. I have to do a task where a User XYZ create an order. after X time (30 minutes for example) certain actions are done on this order automatically according to the actions that another user will have had to do during his 30 minutes

To achieve this system I thought I could achieve it in a basic way by doing: that when I create the task, I associate an expiration date field (TimeNow + 30 minutes) and then I do a cron that checks every minute for each spot if it has already expired.

Is there any other approach to do this? I find this a basic one for my approach, because assuming that the cron every minute must check more than 20,000 active commands in order to check what has already expired, it will be a bit greedy in server resources

Comment: Store the expiry time in the session, and then compare current time against the time in the session when you need to

Comment: in my opinion cron is the best solution, you can create another table with the id of order and the date, every time you will check on the new table instead of 20K row, then you delete the entry from the new table to remain it fresh

Comment: I´d say the same as adnen, you might also not do this every minute but for example clear them every 5 minutes, but i dont think that you would actually have any performance isssues

Comment: Depends on what the tasks (actions) are, eg: send an email, update a record in the DB, generate files, etc. There are quite a few options, such as [messenger component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/messenger.html), [Cron CLI setup](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/24-cron.html) or [third-party Cron bundle](https://github.com/Cron/Symfony-Bundle). Not sure where the *check more than 20,000 active commands* thought came in to play, but the idea would be to specify and store which of them to check and their expiration in a DB or text file.